# Overdetermined equation system

Tags: system

how can I solve this overdetermined equation system with the command PseudoInverse.
[image]

left = Table[(-i)^i, {i, 1, 4}];
     right1 = Table[Sum[2^(i*k)*Sin[Subscript[x, k]], {k, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}];

```
 right2 =Table[Sum[2^(i*k)*Cos[Subscript[x, k]], {k, 2, 3}], {i, 1, 4}]; 
 StringForm["left side = ``", left // MatrixForm] 
 StringForm["right1 side = ``", right1 // MatrixForm]
 StringForm["right2 side = ``", right2 // MatrixForm]
 A1 =  {{2, 4, 8},{4, 16, 64},{8, 64, 512},{16, 256, 4096}};  
 A2 = {{4, 8},{16, 64},{64, 512},{256, 4096}};
 b ={{-1},{4},{-27},{256}};
 x1 = PseudoInverse[Subscript[A, 1]].b // N;
 x2 = PseudoInverse[Subscript[A, 2]].b // N;
 r1 = Subscript[A, 1].Subscript[x, 1] - b // MatrixForm;
 r2 = Subscript[A, 2].Subscript[x, 2] - b // MatrixForm;
 r1 = Flatten[{{r1[[1, 1]]},{r1[[1, 2]]},{r1[[1, 3]]},{r1[[1, 4]]}}];
 r2 = Flatten[{r2[[1, 1]]},{r2[[1, 2]]},{r2[[1, 3]]},{r2[[1, 4]]}}];
 g1 = Length[Subscript[r, 1]];
 g2 = Length[Subscript[r, 2]];
 p1 = Sqrt[Subscript[r, 1].Subscript[r, 1]/Subscript[g, 1]];
 p2 = Sqrt[Subscript[r, 2].Subscript[r, 2]/Subscript[g, 2]];
 Print["r1 = ", r1 // MatrixForm, "\np1 = ", p1]
 Print["r2 = ", r2 // MatrixForm, "\np2 = ", p2]
```

Comment: Please, share the code in copyable and syntactically correct form. Also, this is not a linear system of equations, so `Pseudoinverse` cannot be applied directly. The method of choice would proabably be the Gauß-Newton algorithm (or rather the Levenberg-Marquardt variant). It is employed by `FindMininum` if you  reformulate your problem as a regression or parameter fitting problem. `FindFit` and friends might also be of help here.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a linear system of equations, so Pseudoinverse cannot be applied directly. The method of choice would proabably be the Gauß-Newton algorithm (or rather its Levenberg-Marquardt variant). Under the hood, it employs pseudoinverses of the linearizations of the system.

The Levenberg-Marquardt method is employed by `FindMininum` and probably also by `NMinimize` if one reformulates the problem as a regression or parameter fitting problem:

```
eq = Table[(-i)^(-i) - Sum[(-2)^(k i) If[k == 1, Cos[x[k]], Sin[x[k]]], {k, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}];
sol = NMinimize[Total[eq^2], Table[x[k], {k, 1, 3}]]
```

> {0.709009, {x[1] -> 1.44635, x[2] -> 0.00659458, x[3] -> -0.000899084}}

As you can see, a solution to your system could not be found, as the minimal value is `0.709009` rather far away from `0.`.

`FindFit` and friends might also be of help here.

## Edit

Daniel's comment below rang a bell. The following show that not solution exists because the right hand side of the equations does not lie within the image of the matrix `A` (because it is not perpendicular to the orthogonal complement of the image of `A` which is the null space of `Transpose[A]`):

```
vars = {Cos[x[1]], Sin[x[2]], Sin[x[3]]};
left = Table[Sum[(-2)^(k i) vars[[k]], {k, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}];
right = Table[(-i)^(-i), {i, 1, 4}];
A = D[left, {vars, 1}];

NullSpace[A\[Transpose]][[1]].right
```

> 133129/2304

Actually,

```
Solve[left == right, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]
```

> {}

tells us the same.

If the right hand side were in the image of `A`, all solutions of the equations could be obtained by the following:

```
pinv = PseudoInverse[A].right;
Solve[vars == pinv, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]
```

Notice that `Nullspace[A]` returns `{}`, so `A` is injective and these would be indeed all solutions. In our case, there are no solutions of your equations, so what `Solve` returns here is the set of *least squares* solutions.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher

Comment: @MohsenOmrani ???

Comment: @ Henrik SchumacherI wrote the code in the main post. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: @MohsenOmrani I have no idea how the code that you have posted is related to the previously defined problem. Once more: The system in the beginning of your most is _nonlinear_.

Comment: Difficult wording notwithstanding, it appears to be linear in the trigs.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Good point! It lead me derive a proof that there are no solutions.